# sed - matching multiple lines and insert above the match

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file that looks like this

```
#multi
#line
#comment
$var1=foo

#multi
#line
#comment
$var2=bar

#############################################
#   END                                     #
#############################################
```

using sed (since i am already using sed in other places in my script and i would prefer to remain consistent) how can I match the "END" section i.e one or more comment marks followed by a coment + space + END and then add the following lines **before** the end section

```
#############################################
# user login
#############################################

server.user=$USER
server.pswd=$PASSWD

<newline>
<newline>
```

please comment you answer so I can learn and hopefully not need to ask a followup question

thanks !

Comment: Consistency is good when it doesn't cause undue complexity due to using the wrong tool for a job. Sometimes, though, you find yourself in a situation where switching tools might be a better option. Unless it sounds reasonable to build a new wall with a sledgehammer and crowbar, just because those are the same tools you used to tear down the old wall...

Comment: of course ! but since in unix there is always more than way to do it i wanted to prefer sed if possible without wasting peoples time with answers using awk,perl,etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sed '/^##* END$/i\
# user login\
#############################################\
\
server.user=$USER\
server.pswd=$PASSWD\
\
\
#############################################' input
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the header block of the END section is only one line and is the same as the header of the inserted block so that we are re-using the first line of the END section as the first line of the header of the new section, and writing a new first line for the END block header.  The `i` command tells sed to insert text before the buffer is printed, and the escaped newlines allow us to insert multiple lines of text.

Comment: "This takes advantage of the fact that the header block of the END section is only one line and is the same as the header of the inserted block" Lovely! :-)

Comment: thanks for this. However it does not seem to match the 2 conditions (^#* followed by a line that starts with #\s END) that i would have preferred so i would always know that the text was inserted before the end block and not before where someone had inserted a single comment further up in the file i.e ## END OF THE WORLD IS COMING. can sed match multilines ?